# Font and Color Setting for Text Editor T-SQL Variable Declaration Data Type Size

Tags: visual-studio-2010, vssettings

I can't find the VS2010 Tools | Options... | Environment | Fonts and Colors Text Editor setting for controlling the foreground color of the numeric literal that defines the size of T-SQL variable datatypes like varchar, char.

My problem is that my font and color settings (which I donwloaded from a blog post - maybe Scott Haselman's, not sure) has a black background for the text editor and black foreground for the numeric literal. So when I type `DECLARE @myvar varchar(100)`, I cannot see the "100".

Anyone know what setting I should be looking for? I've been through the list several times trying various settings.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I found the solution. I was looking for the "Number" display item for "Text Editor".

It's weird though, the setting was for a "Default" foreground color which showed as White in the preview window. The actual color was Black. Also, when editing C#, I don't have this problem (this was the first time I used VS2010 for editing SQL - I normally use SSMS).

I think there is a bug in VS2010 as it didn't use the Default color.